# Schema for a lease platform

Tags: database-design, schema

I have following tables:

- A **room** I want to lease (has user.id as ForeignKey)
- A **users** table for users who can rent
  it
- An **availability** table for time periods the room is to use with
  prices for that specific period
- A **transaction** table with check-in
  and out dates (has member.id and room.id as ForeignKey
- A **billing** table

How will I handle the billing?

[image: Schema]

[image: Billing so far]

Billing so far:

Comment: Did you try anything at least? Some diagram or structure? A little bit of information about what you're trying to do could be helpful.

Comment: @oNare: Yes, I've attached the four tables above.

Answer (score 5):

If I were you I would make sure to separate all of the data. Is this going to be completely controlled in the database, or is there going to be an application? If it is an application I would have a users table and permissions tables for the people using the application. I would do a separate a customers table for your customers. I agree with the availability table, but if you are using a price based system I would store that separately. For billing I would set up a few tables. I would have a payment type table and a transaction table with due dates. I like the idea of a check in and out table as well.

Comment: It's a webapplication with a database behind. I'm not sure how I would connect the availability table? I want to keep everything in one database as for now. What do you mean by separately? What kind of tables would you set up and how would you connect them?

Answer (score 4):

I have done one structure that may help you.

- ***room***. It's the main room configuration where you can add any value that refer to the rooms.
- ***room_status***. It's the `room` status where you could know which is the room actual status.
- ***transaction***. Its your main table, here you're going to storage all the activities of the *room*s.
- ***user***. Here you can delimit which user is who.

You should make a try and add the indexes in the fields your going to filter in your queries.

### **CREATE SCRIPT AND INFORMATION:**

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE `room` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `roomName` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `othersfields` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `room_status` (
  `idroom_status` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `sName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idroom_status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `room_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `check_in` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `check_out` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `othersfields` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pwd` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rol` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Information:**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test.room;
+----+----------+---------------------+--------+--------------+
| id | roomName | date                | status | othersfields |
+----+----------+---------------------+--------+--------------+
|  1 | Suit     | 2015-07-13 00:00:00 |      1 | NULL         |
|  2 | Normal   | NULL                |      2 | NULL         |
|  3 | Other    | NULL                |      1 | NULL         |
+----+----------+---------------------+--------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test.room_status;
+---------------+-------------+
| idroom_status | sName       |
+---------------+-------------+
|             1 | Open        |
|             2 | Closed      |
|             3 | Maintenance |
+---------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test.user;
+----+-------+-------+------------+------+
| id | fName | lName | pwd        | rol  |
+----+-------+-------+------------+------+
|  1 | oNare | Test  | 123ka21312 | NULL |
+----+-------+-------+------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test.transaction;
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------+
| id | room_id | check_in            | check_out           | user_id | othersfields |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2015-07-01 00:00:00 | 2015-07-02 00:00:00 |       1 | NULL         |
|  2 |       1 | 2015-07-03 00:00:00 | 2015-07-05 00:00:00 |       1 | NULL         |
|  3 |       2 | 2015-07-03 00:00:00 | 2015-07-04 00:00:00 |       1 | NULL         |
|  4 |       1 | 2015-07-13 00:00:00 | NULL                |       1 | NULL         |
|  5 |       2 | 2015-07-09 00:00:00 | 2015-07-13 00:00:00 |       1 | NULL         |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**Test query:**

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> r.id AS idRoom,
    ->     r.roomName,
    ->     rs.sName as Status,
    ->     t.check_in,
    ->     t.check_out
    -> FROM test.transaction AS t
    -> JOIN test.room AS r ON (t.room_id=r.id)
    -> JOIN test.room_status AS rs ON (rs.idroom_status=r.status)
    -> JOIN test.user AS u ON (t.user_id=u.id);
+--------+----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| idRoom | roomName | Status | check_in            | check_out           |
+--------+----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      1 | Suit     | Open   | 2015-07-01 00:00:00 | 2015-07-02 00:00:00 |
|      1 | Suit     | Open   | 2015-07-03 00:00:00 | 2015-07-05 00:00:00 |
|      1 | Suit     | Open   | 2015-07-13 00:00:00 | NULL                |
|      2 | Normal   | Closed | 2015-07-03 00:00:00 | 2015-07-04 00:00:00 |
|      2 | Normal   | Closed | 2015-07-09 00:00:00 | 2015-07-13 00:00:00 |
+--------+----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration. I guess my question is more how I can connect the avaibility table in my schema. I will add the suggested status field to this table. I guess this is the only thing new to it? (from, till in this table are dates).

Comment: You can add an `id_room` on your table `availability` so you can `JOIN` `room.id` with `availability.id_room` easily.

Comment: That's exactly what I did in the meantime. But now how to connect the transaction table? To make it even more complicated I brought the billing table in too. (See update above.)

Comment: You just need to add the `billing_id` into `transaction` table because `transaction` is your master table, you could `JOIN` it with every table.

Comment: And would you join the payment table(Columns(id, paymenttype[Paypal, Visa]) rather with billing table (as I thought) or the transaction table as well?

Comment: No, the paymenttype could be in the billing table because it belongs to the billing

Comment: Thx. Thinking about it it more deeply, it would be neat if the operator (me) could choose if he accepts the transaction or not, before there is a bill. Is a flat in transaction the right way to handle this?

Comment: You could manage this as `status` in `transaction` table.

Comment: Thank you. What is still unclear to me is how room, transaction and availability could be related. (I added another image above.)

Answer (score 3):

I will use pseudo code to illustrate; you can adapt to your DBMS's specific syntax.

Join `availability` to `transaction` on `room.id` and also on the overlapping intervals i.e.

```
    Availability.from <= TimePartOf(transaction.checkout)
And availability.til >= TimePartOf(transaction.checkin)
```

If, for example, a room had different rates in the morning and afternoon and your transaction went from 11am to 2pm the above would now show two rows. Some simple `DateDiff()` maths will give you the duration of each billable rate i.e. 11am to noon and noon to 2pm. Multiply by the rate, `SUM()` the result and `GROUP BY` the user id.

<strike>You will need a flag on transaction to show which rows have been billed and which not.</strike>

Edit: on further reflection it looks like a row in the `billing` table is a single invoice (i.e. bill) set to a user.  Rather than add a flag to `transaction` add the foreign key to `billing`.  Then you will know not only that a transaction has been billed but exactly when and how.  Note that billing systems, invoicing and payment is a specialist subject in itself and full of intricacies.

Comment: I don't quite get it. I will lease on days on a fixed price not in hours. But periods may overlap so your principle holds true. Currently room.id is a ForeignKey of availability. Shall I make room.id a ForeignKey of transaction as well? Will add the flag.

Comment: According to your question "A transaction table ... has ... room.id as ForeignKey."  If that's not true how do you know what a user is paying for when you record a transaction?

Comment: That's right the drawing above (new version) is conflicting with my text  above. I'm not sure how I have to connect both of them (meaning availability and transaction tables with rooms and member tables).