# Schema for scarce goods

Tags: database-design, schema

I have following objects:
(Rooms) which are (available in a certain period of time [in days]).
During the time of availability they can be (booked) by (users). There are basically these four tables. I know that there is a foreign key in (booked) for (users), I also have a foreign key for (rooms) in (booking) and I do have a foreign key of the (room) in (availability). But how can I connect my (availability)-table to avoid that the good is booked on a period of time it isn't available?

The refered question didn't lead to an answer in my matter.

To summarize:
(Rooms) - (availability) - (booking) - (User)

I have a hard time figuring out how I set the foreign keys for this transaction.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Schema for a lease platform](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106818/schema-for-a-lease-platform)

Comment: No concise answer to the question has been given over there.

Comment: @MichaelGreen I see that the 2 questions are related but the question asked there was about billings. Here it's about a different thing. But @emdedokles, please use `room` and not `good`. The `id_room` is confusing (or change it to `id_good`.)

Answer (score 0):

The most relational way is adding a `day` table. You will be able to `join` `room`, `availability` and day to find out which rooms are available for a certain period.

Comment: I already have date fields (from and till) in the availability table. Why isn't this enough?

Comment: How do you find out if a room is available for a specific date? Performing a BETWEEN is less efficient. Also, with the relational solution you can ask questions like "How much days the room 212 was reserved, last year?"

Comment: I thought about doing a if transaction.check_in is > availability.from and transaction.check_out is < availability.till it would allow a reservation. I don't quite understand what you are proposing. Can you draw it in a simplified version? What fields does your table day contain?

Answer (score 0):

> (Rooms) - (availability) - (booking) - (User)

*room:*

```
room_id
description
address
```

*user:*

```
user_id
name
phone
```

*room_availability:*

```
availability_id
room_id: room_id of room table [relationship]
start_dt
end_dt
price
is_available
```

This table has all the availability information for each room. Note the `is_available` flag. Also, there need check that for a room the set of start_dt and end_dt values do not overlap for a room's availability. For example, some available rooms:

- room_1 - 24-Dec-2023 and 28-Dec-2023
- room_1 - 31-Dec-2023 and 31-Dec-2023
- room_1 - 30-Dec-2023 and 2-Jan-2024 <--- this data is not valid

*booking_transaction:*

```
booking_id
booked_by: user_id of user table [relationship]
availability_id: availability_id of room_availability table [relationship]
booked_from
booked_to
amount
payment_details
```

Now, having a unique constraint on the `booking_transaction.availability_id` will ensure that a room that is booked for a set of available dates (i.e., room availability) cannot be booked again. Also, the is_available flag can tell if the room is available or not. This can address the issue asked in the question post:

> But how can I connect my (availability)-table to avoid that the good
> is booked on a period of time it isn't available?